# Select data from hour of week

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I want to select data between hours of week.
An example would be to select all data between the following hours:

- Mondays 10:00-16:00
- Tuesdays 3:00-18:00
- Wednesdays 15:00-18:00
- Thursdays 13:00-19:00
- Fridays 13:00-19:00
- Saturdays 13:00-19:00
- Sundays 13:00-19:00

The date is noted as UTC in the database, I would like a solution where I can choose the timezone.

How would I select these data using C#/Entity Framework/MSSQL?

The following is an example MSSQL query I am making to get data by time of week, but this does not take timezone into account

```
select 
    cast(AVG(cast(success as float)*100) as decimal(18,2)) Avg,
    convert(date,time) Time
from 
    recordings
where 
    Id = @Id
    and time >= @startDate 
    and time <= @endDate
    AND (
        (CAST(time AS TIME) BETWEEN @mondayStart AND @mondayEnd AND DATENAME(DW, time) = 'Monday')
        OR (CAST(time AS TIME) BETWEEN @tuesdayStart and @tuesdayEnd AND DATENAME(DW, time) = 'Tuesday')
        OR (CAST(time AS TIME) BETWEEN @wednesdayStart and @wednesdayEnd AND DATENAME(DW, time) = 'Wednesday')
        OR (CAST(time AS TIME) BETWEEN @thursdayStart and @thursdayEnd AND DATENAME(DW, time) = 'Thursday')
        OR (CAST(time AS TIME) BETWEEN @fridayStart and @fridayEnd AND DATENAME(DW, time) = 'Friday')
        OR (CAST(time AS TIME) BETWEEN @saturdayStart and @saturdayEnd AND DATENAME(DW, time) = 'Saturday')
        OR (CAST(time AS TIME) BETWEEN @sundayStart and @sundayEnd AND DATENAME(DW, time) = 'Sunday')
    )
group by 
    convert(date, time)
order by 
    convert(date, time)
```

Comment: Share table data.

Comment: Hello, I should make an attempt first and show your code before you get downvoted. SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: You can try converting hour ranges from a particular timezone to UTC and perform the query.

Comment: Thank you for your comments - I have updated the question to include the MSSQL call I am using right now.
I hope that this is sufficient, all the code is rather complex and too much for a SO-question.

Answer (score -1):

```
var result = context.YourEntityName.Where(entry => entry.DateField >= minDate && entry.DateField <= maxDate).ToList();
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate your code and explain it a little bit?